# Import dataset from Kaggle to Databricks with Kaggle's API

Tags: databricks, kaggle

Here trying to import a dataset from **Kaggle **to **DataBricks **(community) with their Kaggle' **API**, but I'm falling and lost 3 days. Please a kind soul can help me.

**Trying 1:**

```
!pip install kaggle

import os
import kaggle

os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = 'xxxxxx'
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = 'xxxxx'

from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KaggleApi

api = KaggleApi()
api.authenticate()

api.dataset_download_files('taricov/mobile-wallets-in-egypt-2020')
```

**Trying 1 error:**

[image: Error trying 1]

**Trying 2:**

```
import os
import kaggle

from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KaggleApi
api = KaggleApi()
api_token_path = '/FileStore/tables/Kaggle_token/kaggle-2.json'
os.environ['KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR'] = os.path.dirname(api_token_path)

api.dataset_download_files('taricov/mobile-wallets-in-egypt-2020', path='/FileStore/mobile-wallets-in-egypt-2020',unzip=True)
```

**Trying 2 error:**

[image: Error trying 2]

My kaggle.json credential in Databricks:

[image: kaggle credential]

I try two types of connections but its missing something or my credentials are wrong because the error is:

> "Reason: Unauthorized".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
import os
import kaggle

from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KaggleApi
api = KaggleApi()
api_token_path = '/FileStore/tables/Kaggle_token/kaggle-2.json'
os.environ['KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR'] = os.path.dirname(api_token_path)
api.authenticate()

api.dataset_download_files('taricov/mobile-wallets-in-egypt-2020', path='/FileStore/mobile-wallets-in-egypt-2020',unzip=True)
```

It seems that in your first snippet there is missing the environment variables and in the second one there is no api.authenticate() being called. Inside this method there is the **read_config_environment** method that is responsible to get those keys.

[image: Authenticate method in the api]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you're trying to reference file on DBFS directly `/Filestore/...`, but Kaggle API doesn't know anything about that filesystem because it uses Python's local file API.  You have two choices:

- Refer to DBFS path directly by prepending the `/dbfs` to file names. Like, `/dbfs/FileStore/tables/Kaggle_token/kaggle-2.json` instead of `/FileStore/tables/Kaggle_token/kaggle-2.json`
- Use DBUtils commands to copy files to local disks or upload downloaded data to DBFS. For example, to copy file to local disk you can use following (not the `file:` prefix):

```py
import os
conf_dir = "/tmp/kaggle-conf"
os.mkdir(conf_dir)
dbutils.fs.cp('/FileStore/tables/Kaggle_token/kaggle-2.json', 
  f'file:{conf_dir}/kaggle.json')
os.environ['KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR'] = conf_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import json

# Define the content of the kaggle.json file
data = {
    "username": "XXXXXXX",
    "key": "XXXXXXXXXX"
}

# Convert the data to a JSON string
json_string = json.dumps(data)

# Put the JSON string into the DBFS
dbutils.fs.put('file:/databricks/driver/kaggle.json', json_string, overwrite=True)

# Move the kaggle.json file from the DBFS to the driver node's local file system
dbutils.fs.cp('file:/databricks/driver/kaggle.json', 'file:/root/.kaggle/kaggle.json')

# Set appropriate permissions on the kaggle.json file
os.system("chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json")
```